# how to remove two second copy of pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this code for generating a pdf file and save it in a folder of my invoice but it saves two copy one in the folder and one in google drive out of all folders, how to remove send copy of pdf in drive but not in folder.
the code is

```
function runBothfunctions(){
//function 1
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1')
var ss1Id = ss1.getSheetId()
var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2')
var ssId = ss.getId()
var clientName = ss1.getRange(3,3).getValue()
var invoiceNumber = ss1.getRange(4,3).getValue()
var totalBill = ss1.getRange(29,9).getValue()
var d = new Date();
var fullDate = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) +"/"+ ('0' + (d.getMonth()    +1)).slice(-2) +"/"+ (d.getYear().toString()).slice(-2)
var invoiceFileName = invoiceNumber + '_' + fullDate + '_' + clientName +'_'+ totalBill

var url = ss.getUrl()
url = url.replace(/edit$/,'')
var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
+ '&size=A4'                           // paper    size: "legal" / "letter" / "A4"
+ '&fitw=true'                         // fit to width, false for actual size
+ '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
+ '&gridlines=false'                   // hide gridlines
+ '&gid=' + ss1Id                      // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()  
// Convert sheet1 to PDF
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, { headers:   { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token }})

var blob = response.getBlob().setName(invoiceFileName + '.pdf')  
 // Add the folder ID of the Drive folder where the PDF should be saved.   Create a folder and copy this ID: www.goo.gl/TfgqrN
var invoiceURL = DriveApp.getFolderById('19_cTkcDHlekS-  7Y32BEzUVlhghC0UHMZ').createFile(blob).getUrl()
 ss2.getRange(ss2.getLastRow() +1, 1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' +   invoiceURL + '";"' + invoiceFileName + '")')

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

//create an array of the invoice numbers already created 
var colArray = sheet.getRange(4, 3).getValues();

//sort the array values to find max
var maxInColumn = colArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0][
```

Comment: Are you saying that this line `var invoiceURL = DriveApp.getFolderById('19_cTkcDHlekS-  7Y32BEzUVlhghC0UHMZ').createFile(blob).getUrl();` creates two copies?

Comment: yeah one in folder and one out of all folders , then everyday I delete it, because I need only in folder